# How to correctly change MinSDKVersion from 15 to 16 for firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I was originally using minSDKVersion 15, but now have to change to 16 because I need to implement firebase. Using the previous version of firebase is not an option.

Simply changing the minSDKVersion to 16 in the build.gradle(Module:app) gives the following error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-40:19 to override.
```

I did try the suggestion it provides to add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to the  element in AndroidManifest.xml but that produces even more errors.

I changed my build.gradle(Module:app) file from this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.comapny.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
}
```

to this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dataletix.gr8"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try to downgrade the firebase dependency from `17.0.0` to `16.0.7`

This is the version that I'm currently using and it works.

Be very careful about firebase versions. There are some dependencies that will crash your project if you set the wrong version.

Here is a list of some stable dependencies that I use:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
```

Comment: right, i ended up doing something similar, I went to 16.0.9 instead. It really bugs me though that it doesn't work normally.